# jQuery Dialog but get dynamic inputs

Tags: php, jquery

All,
I'm trying to send an email with the jQuery dialog modal window. I can get the window to populate correctly and everything like that however I'm trying to populate some email addresses when I open the dialog window. Here is the jQuery to open the dialog window:

```
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 600,
    width: 750,
    modal: true,
    show: 'slide',
    buttons: {
        "Send Email": function() {
                var message_to_send = $( "#message_to_vendors" ).val();
                alert(message_to_send);
                var vendor_ids = $("#email_vendor_ids").val();
                alert(vendor_ids);
                $.post("send_vendor_emails.php", { email_vendor_ids: vendor_ids, message_to_vendors: message_to_send }, function(data) {
                    alert("The data is: "+data);
                    if(data=="yes"){
                        $("#dialog-form").dialog( "close" );
                    }
               });

        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
});
```

Then here is my dialog form:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Email Vendors">
<form>
<select data-placeholder="Vendors to Email" style="width:350px;" multiple class="chzn-select">
<div id="email_options">
<option selected>Email Address 1</option>
<option selected>Email Address 2</option>
</div>
</select>
</form>
</div>
```

I'm storing some email addresses in session variables and what I'd like to happen is when I click the dialog box to open it up that I can populate the email addresses in the Session variables. How can I do that with the dialog box?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to print out the emails from your session into the markup for your dialog box.  You're wanting to add them as options for the select element, right?

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Email Vendors">
<form>
<div id="email_options">
<select data-placeholder="Vendors to Email" style="width:350px;" multiple class="chzn-select">

<?php foreach ( $_SESSION['emails'] as $e ): ?>
    <option><?php echo $e; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Assuming the emails are stored as array in `$_SESSION['emails']`.  I also moved your email_options div outside of the select for the sake of valid XHTML.

**Update**

Since you clarified that users are able to add emails to the session on the fly after the page is loaded, when you add emails to the session you should use some JavaScript to keep your session and the dialog box synchronized.  Something like this:

```
/* Where ever you update the session with more emails, also do this
Note, this is using the modified markup from my above example 
(select is child of #email_optons) */

var new_email = '';  // Set this to the value of the email which is being added to the session

$('#email_options select').append( $('<option>' + new_email + '</option>' ) );
```

Comment: Yes, that would get the sessions when the page loads though. Once on the page the user can still select more checkboxes which create more session variables and those wouldn't show up since you've populated when the page loads instead of when the dialog box is called to be opened.

Comment: You should clarify this in your original question.  I updated the answer to reflect this, though I'm still not 100% clear on whether you are referring to a PHP session or something else.

Comment: Thanks and yes I was referring to the PHP session. However the append isn't working. Any ideas why it wouldn't be doing that?

Comment: It's hard to say without some updated code to reference.  Did you restructure the HTML to match my example?  For simplicity, you might just add `id="email_select"` to your `<select>` element.  Then use this  jQuery code `$('#email_select').append( $('<option>' + new_email + '</option>' ) );` to append the new email, noting that `new_email` should be set to the email address that is being added to the session.